I want to inherit the res partner module in odoo, but this error appears - can anyone help me?
I want to inherit the res partner module in odoo to my custom module but this error was appear how any one can help me?
The error is:
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column res_partner.partner_type does not exist
LINE 1: ..._partner"."phone_sanitized" as "phone_sanitized", "res_partn...
My res_partner module:
from odoo import models, fields
class ResPartner(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'res.partner'

 partner_type = fields.Selection(
    selection=[
        ('individual', 'Individual'),
        ('organization', 'Organization'),  # New partner type
        ('customer', 'Customer'),
        ('supplier', 'Supplier'),
        # Add more types as needed
    ],
    string='partner_type',
    default='individual',
    help='Type of partner: Individual, Organization, Customer, or Supplier.'
)

My res_parner_view:
      <odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="view_partner_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <<xpath expr="//field[@name='vat']" position="after">
                    <field name="partner_type"/>
                </xpath>>

            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>

How can I fix this error?
anyone know the solution?

First of all, be sure that your error is caused by that class that you created.
Remove it, and check if you still have an error.
If the error persists, make sure that your inherit is in a different Module, than the original ResPartner.
You can't create a inherit of an already existing class, in the same module.

To Solve this,
Please Restart Odoo Server and Update your app, if you are Odoo.sh User then Update app from Shell using this command: odoo-update custom_app_name
